# Set array of values to SQL query

Tags: jdbc

I'm using JDBC, I have to set array of values to a single column, 
I know it works in Hibernate and Ibatis but it seems to be hard to get it working Pure JDBC sql.

I have an array of String values

```
names[] = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
```

and a Query like

```
select * from emp where name in(?)
```

I tried pstmt.setObject(1,names), it is not working..

Comment: You might get there if you create your query string dynamically and add ?s for each item in your array, and then bind each one of them to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in pure JDBC. You have to generate a query so that the `in` clause contains one placeholder for each element of the array.

Spring's JDBC helper classes support named parameters and what you want to do.

Comment: I think it is supported in JDBC now - see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with the following Syntax:

```
"SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name IN ( SELECT column_value FROM TABLE( ? ) )"

pmst.setArray( 1, conn.createArrayOf( "VARCHAR", names ) );
```

Comment: Note that `createArrayOf` might not work across all major relational databases. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28400518/59087

Comment: There are several tricks to get it to work with other Vendors, But it is a hassle you need a separate case for each DBMS...